# Run Python Script until it matches the required result

Tags: python, jquery, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I am trying to scrape some data from a website, which is dynamically updated after some time. it means that I am scraping some HTML divs which do not exist in the page every time.

I want to get a number from it, copy it and paste it when I want.

So far, I have tried to do something like this, which is giving me the result locally. but when I do it online to scrape from the website, it gives me an error, because that HTML element does not exist.

I want the script to run even after the error occurs because I am sure that if it matches the element, it will do its work.

My code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
import re
import time
import pyperclip


while True:

    page_url = "https://www.example.com/"

    uClient = uReq(page_url)

    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")


    numbers = page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'}).find('span').get_text()
    time.sleep(5*60)
```

Its giving me this Error.

```
  File "t.py", line 23, in <module>
    codes = page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'}).find('span').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Can anyone help me with issue?

Comment: `try...except: pass`

Comment: @PedroLobito The script is now working fine. I have tested it locally. It does what I want it to. but when trying to do it online from the website, it runs fine, there is no error, but it does not give me the result, since that span which I am trying to scrape is appearing once in every 5 minutes, using some jquery script I think. What do you think, why is this not catching that span, when it appears on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing it all in one line, I suggest you do it step by step, with checks if everything in-between is defined. From:

```
numbers = page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'}).find('span').get_text()
```

to

```
div = page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'})
if div:
    span = div.find('span')
    if not span:
        # maybe sleep, increase attemts?
        continue
    numbers = span.get_text()
    ...
```

Because soup returns None, if no match, so you are trying to call None.get_text(..), which is not right

Edit: changed the code to continue on (not span) rather than div

Edit: whole code should look like this now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen  # Web client
import re
import time
import pyperclip

page_url = "https://www.example.com/"
while True:
    with urlopen(page_url) as response: # urlopen is a resource. with statement closes the resource after you stop using it.
        page_soup = soup(response.read(), "html.parser")

        if div := page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'}):# see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html
            if span := div.find('span'): 
                numbers = span.get_text()
                match = re.search('\d{5,}', numbers)
                card = match.group(0)
                pyperclip.copy(card)
                pyperclip.paste()
                # break
    time.sleep(5*60)
```

Comment: `File "t.py", line 26
    continue
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` Can you please update it without errors?

Comment: Don't know. I have clear code. Why is there inconsistent use of tabs and spaces?

Comment: So.. Stackoverflow's editor doesn't allow tabs in code, or at least I do not know the way to use them... replace margin of indented lines with tabs

Comment: I like your idea, let me fix the indentation error.

Comment: @AljažMedič Solved all the errors. but still not working because that specific tag `span` does not exist and it gives me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "t.py", line 25, in <module> numbers = div.find('span').get_text() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' ` the `span` will appear only once in 5 or 10 minutes, so I want the script to look for that `span` and when it appears, do the remaining work. otherwise, loop.

Comment: @AljažMedič The script is now working fine. I have tested it locally. It does what I want it to. but when trying to do it online from the website, it runs fine, there is no error, but it does not give me the result, since that span which I am trying to scrape is appearing once in every 5 minutes, using some jquery script I think. What do you think, why is this not catching that span, when it appears on the website?

Comment: @Aayush Khawaja Try saving the html file every time the script finds a div, then look at it and see where the problem arises...

Comment: Something like:
`import datetime as dt

if(divs):
 with open(f"page_{dt.datetime.isoformat()}.html",'w') as wf:
  wf.write(str(soup))`

Comment: @AljažMedič I saved it several times and I have it locally even with the span and text which I want to scrape. I run the script, then deleted that span, and the script stops, then added that span back and the script continues, so there is no problem with the script. the problem is why is not getting that span when it is generating online in every 5 minutes. I want it to catch it and scrape it.

Comment: @Aayush Khawaja I copletely unserstand. But perhaps you could try troubleshooting that way: try doing the thing you want, and if you catch error output the whole soup to the file, so you will see, what is up with the span... Maybe there is and edge case or an exception on a website, that you did not anticipate; maybe div doesn't always include the span

Comment: @AljažMedič exactly. the div does not include the span always, the span comes there once in every 5 minutes. otherwise, that div is empty or with some text.

Comment: @Aayush Khawaja Oh, I thaught the div is the questionable tag... then just replace the original script code with search for div.. I will edit my answer

Comment: @AljažMedič then will it scrape the span, when we are looking for a div?

Comment: @Aayush Khawaja
The code should do:
1. look for the div
2. if div -> look for the span
3. if span -> process
4. if any of it is none, just sleep and continue

Comment: @AljažMedič I was testing it for 15 minutes, the span and its text generated on the website and I saw, but the script did not catch them even with that. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Aayush Khawaja I would suggest you to put print sptatements in-between lines. print the div between ifs and span after second if, print the span.get_text() etc...
try running for few times, then post the console output as an edit to your question. It would be easier if you shared the url, but if you don't want its also ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try` and `except`, e.g

```
try:
    numbers = page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'}).find('span').get_text()
except:
    pass
```

Though having `try` and `except` within a `while True` loop is generally not advised as you'll likely get into an infinite loop. You can get around this by adding a `break` condition, e.g

```
attempts=0

while True:
    if attempts==10:
        break
    page_url = "https://www.example.com/"

    uClient = uReq(page_url)

    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

    try:
        numbers = page_soup.find('div',{'id':'number-id'}).find('span').get_text()
        match = re.search('\d{5,}', numbers)
        card = match.group(0)
        pyperclip.copy(card)
        pyperclip.paste()
    except:
        attempts+=1


    time.sleep(5*60)
```

That will fail up to 10 times before breaking out of the `While` loop, just change the `if attempts==10:` to a larger number if needed.

Comment: I want an infinite loop there. let me try your advice.

Comment: I tried to use your code. got this error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 28, in <module>
    match = re.search('\d{5,}', numbers)
NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined`

Comment: @Aayush: of course it does, when there is no `numbers` to act upon when that previous line failed.

Comment: @Aayush: [The Python tutorial on Exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=errors). Your other comments suggest you may need to start at [the beginning](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), though.

Comment: @KJTHoward The script is now working fine. I have tested it locally. It does what I want it to. but when trying to do it online from the website, it runs fine, there is no error, but it does not give me the result, since that span which I am trying to scrape is appearing once in every 5 minutes, using some jquery script I think. What do you think, why is this not catching that span, when it appears on the website?